# Adjective + Pronoun - what kind of sentence structure is that?

Tags: sentence-structure

I was teaching English to my daughter and stuck up with this structure.

> Adjective + pronoun

Say,

> Poor him!

She said that there is no preposition between the adjective and pronoun like *'Shame **on** you.' [sic]* This all came when she asked about the latest movie *'Despicable Me.'*

Help me to answer her! :)

Comment: This may be interesting to you [**Why do we use the object instead of the subject pronoun in constructions like “stupid me”?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/why-do-we-use-the-object-instead-of-the-subject-pronoun-in-constructions-like-s) and this too [**Poor 'him' or 'he'? Reason?**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47264/poor-him-or-he-reason)

Comment: You’re blessed to have such a smart daughter – observant her!

Comment: Actually, it's simply an exclamation expressing sympathy "**Poor him!**"

Answer (score 1):

It's a phrase that expresses sympathy for the subject (**him, her, me, it, they, us, you**), it requires third-person concordance. This is done for distancing.

**Poor** is the adjective that modifies the pronoun (which acts as a noun) that is in the objective case. It's grammatically correct to place adjectives before nouns. Any further pronouns should also have third-person usages:

- Stupid me gets himself into trouble again.
- Silly me lost her keys again.
- His wife found out that he was cheating on her. Poor her!

---

1. [Why do we use the object instead of the subject pronoun in constructions like “stupid me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/why-do-we-use-the-object-instead-of-the-subject-pronoun-in-constructions-like-s)
2. [“Despicable Me”: can “me” be used in such a way?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297/despicable-me-can-me-be-used-in-such-a-way)

Comment: But in this case (and generally in PDE) the pronoun is not in nominative but in objective case. Note that Kittredge's grammar is Latinate and very old-fashioned, and not reliable for PDE.

Comment: What does PDE stand for?

Comment: @SovereignSun Present-Day English.

Comment: @StoneyB According to grammar it's in the accusative case (them, him, her, you).

Comment: @SovereignSun Kittredge seems to be just modern enough (in 1913!) to use 'objective' for Lat 'accusative' and 'dative'.

Comment: Note that "Stupid me gets himself" and any other examples where the person appears to change are so awkward for the average speaker that we would usually break it up: "Stupid me! I got **myself** in trouble again." For the third person this isn't an issue ("Clever John got himself a new car with zero down payment.")

Answer (score 0):

"Sentence" is a typographic category, not a grammatical one. This sentence is a noun phrase, not a clause.